# How to access the gradle api in a way that is configuration cache supported?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to access the task api to collect information about which are the source files that JavaCompile task is compiling. Without the configuration cache switched on, it's only the matter of adding a TaskExecutionListener and implementing the functions that the class requires in a way that suits my needs. But, when configuration cache is enabled, this fails, as this isn't supported when the configuration cache is enabled. Is there any work around this problem ? is there any way for me to access various classes like the task and project classes for extracting the needed information ?